# windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Can someone help me to find out how to run my application of windows phone 7 when it is showing me the error/alert as :
"ONE OR MORE PROJECTS NOT LOADED CORRECTLY.PLEASE SEE THE OUTPUT WINDOW".

Comment: did you install WP SDK? are WP7 projects you are trying to load compatible with your WP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are missing a necessary dependency or SDK.  It sounds like the Windows Phone SDK might not be installed.